# replacement in makefile pattern rule

Tags: makefile

I have files like this:

```
IMAGES=img_some_name_1.png img_somename_2.png img_some_other_name_1.png ...
```

where the first two are build by a script

```
some_name.py
```

and the third one by

```
some_other_name.py
```

and so on. I'd like to write something like this makefile rule

```
%.png: $(remove 'img_' and replace '_?.png' with '.py')
    python $<
```

how can I do that replacement in the dependency? I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11205851/2108771) is on the right track, but how can I do the more complicated replacement with the wildcard character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of Make's major shortcomings is its inability to handle wildcards in a sensible way.

Here's a crude but effective approach. Use Make's [string manipulation functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) to split the target into pieces (e.g. "img somename 1") and pick the second one, then add ".py". And don't forget to use `.SECONDEXPANSION` to defer all of this until the wildcard actually has a value.

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.png: $$(word 2,$$(subst _, ,%)).py
    python $<
```

**EDIT:** If the target name can contain underscores, then the pattern rule approach becomes very ungainly. Here's a better way. Suppose we have only one target, `img_some_name_1.png`, so that we can write a rule like this:

```
img_some_name_1.png: some_name.py
    python $<
```

Now we want to be clever (and lazy) and have Make construct the script name from the target name:

```
IMAGE := img_some_name_1.png
SCRAP := $(lastword $(subst _, ,$(IMAGE))) # this is 1.png
SCRIPT := $(patsubst img_%_$(SCRAP),%.py, $(IMAGE)) # this is some_name.py

$(IMAGE): $(SCRIPT)
    @echo python $<
```

We don't want to type all of this for every target, so we define a template:

```
define thing
IMAGE := $(1)
SCRAP := $$(lastword $$(subst _, ,$$(IMAGE)))
SCRIPT := $$(patsubst img_%_$$(SCRAP),%.py, $$(IMAGE))

$$(IMAGE): $$(SCRIPT)
    python $$<
endef

$(eval $(call thing, img_some_name_1.png))
```

And once we've confirmed that that much works (on our version of Make), we iterate over the list of targets:

```
IMAGES=img_some_name_1.png img_somename_2.png img_some_other_name_1.png

allImages: $(IMAGES)

$(foreach IMAGE, $(IMAGES), $(eval $(call thing, $(IMAGE))))
```

Comment: thanks, but actually there are more (variable number) underscores in the names - I updated my original question.

Comment: @JohnSmith: That changes the problem quite a lot. I can see a solution, but it'll take some time to write up...

Comment: yes, I thought so. I should have been clearer from the start. Thanks! I suppose it's best to then add a new answer as this one is quite useful as well.

Comment: trying the latest answer step by step, I have issues ad the third code block. using `@echo` gives me `SCRIPT=img_myscript_1_1.png`, so the `patsubst` apparently does nothing instead of changing it to `some_name.py`. But `SCRAP` works, this gives me `1.png`.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Are you sure it gives you `img_myscript_1_1.png`? The string `myscript` does not appear in that code block. What did you actually do?

Comment: yes, sorry, I used different names in my minimum working example. it now gives `SCRIPT=img_some_name_1.png`. Using exactly what you have there gives me `make: Circular img_some_name_1.png <- img_some_name_1.png dependency dropped.`

Comment: @JohnSmith: I can't reproduce the error, so this may take a few iterations to debug. Try changing `SCRIPT := $$(patsubst img_%_$$(SCRAP),%.py, $$(IMAGE))` to `SCRIPT := $$(patsubst img_%_1.png,%.py, $$(IMAGE))` and see what happens.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Uhh... It works for *all* the targets, or just that one?

Comment: now your solution it works for all files - I think it was another rule (that redoes everything) that interfered with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are willing to build your rules dynamically you can use the [`glob-match` function from gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt/blob/master/README.md#call-glob-matchstringpattern). You can try to cram everything into a `.SECONDEXPANSION`expression  as @Beta proposed but I think this will get quite ugly.

```
include gmtt.mk
IMAGES = img_some_name_1.png img_somename_2.png img_some_other_name_1.png
$(info $(foreach fname,$(IMAGES),$(call glob-match,$(fname),img_*_?.png)))
```

Output:

```
img_ some_name _ 1 .png img_ somename _ 2 .png img_ some_other_name _ 1 .png
```

Now that I tried it, it doesn't seem so ugly(*) after all:

```
%.png: $$(word 2,$$(call glob-match,%,img_*_?)).py
```

If your string building conventions get more involved it can still get nasty, though.

(*) for any definition of "ugly" from the perspective of GNUmake programming.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work for me. `make img_myscript_1_1.png`  just says `make: Nothing to be done for 'img_myscript_1_1.png'.` If I delete it, it says `No rule to make target `img_myscript_1_1.png'.`

Comment: Sorry, put a surplus `.png` to match against `%`. As `%` in only the stem, no filename extension will be given to the prerequisite side. Edited answer.

Comment: ok, it now builds it, however it gets build every time. why does it not stop rebuilding it until I change the python script? I have the rule `all: $(IMAGES)`

Comment: As a very basic 'make' judgement, a rule executing each time, every time until its prerequisites are artificially brought to a newer date means that the rules target doesn't get updated. Do the '.png's' get a new build time when their rules execute? What is the reaction if you add a `touch $@` to the recipe?

Comment: yes, they were. But I think the rerunning it had to do with another rule. I now got the other question to work and accepted that because it works without extra files (`gmat.mk`), but thanks anyway!